# WCF-SAP adapter Send port failing with 'Unknown Error description' error in BizTalk 2013 R2

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

A send port configured with WCF-SAP adapter is failing with `Unknown error description` error logged to Biztalk event log.

In the event of this error we can see that the iDOC is already sent to the SAP system before the error occurred, but due to this error Biztalk thinks that the iDOC has not been sent to SAP and hence retries to send the iDOC after retry interval of 5 minutes which is creating a duplicate of the iDOC in the SAP system as well as in biztalk by archiving 2 files. Not sure of the cause of the error  as it is a very generic error.

Can someone please suggest if you had similar situation or cause for this error anyway related to wcf-sap adapter in BT 2013 R2 ? Thank you.

Here is the error:

> A message sent to adapter "WCF-SAP" on send port "xx" with URI
>   "sap://CLIENT=xx;LANG=EN;@a/xx/xx?GWHOST=xx&GWSERV=xx&ListenerGwServ=xx&ListenerGwHost=xx&RfcSdkTrace=False&AbapDebug=False"
>   is suspended.   Error details: Unknown Error Description    MessageId:
>   {DC121ABC-ECD3-4635-B30D-5080322C976B}  InstanceID:
>   {B2802A71-ECBE-4237-A48D-E5DCE284D23F}

Answer (score 0):

Verify at the adapter settings that `EnableBizTalkCompatibilityMode` is set to `True`. And the checkbox `Use Transactions` is enabled and `Isolation Level` selected is `Serializable`.

Also are you using the `NCo` `ConnectorType` to connect to SAP? This is the recommended way.